# Trouble when using System.io.File in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I hit the following problem when I try to buid a windowsPhone 8 and webPlayer game from Unity:
"error CS0117: `System.IO.File' does not contain a definition for`WriteAllLines'
"
but the System.io.File work fine when I buid the game for android platform, anyone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not available to *Web Player* for security reasons (Unity don't want people making websites that can access the file system) and it's not available to *Windows Store Apps* and *Windows Phone 8* simply because this API doesn't exist in these platforms. It was replaced by the `Windows.Storage` API, and that's what you have to use for these platforms (WSA & WP8).

But... it's not so simple: `Windows.Storage` is not available for Android, etc, so you have to use compilation directives like `#if UNITY_WP8`. You have `UNITY_WINRT`, `UNITY_WP8` and `UNITY_METRO`.

I recommend you take a look at [these porting guides](http://unity3d.com/pages/windows/porting), they'll give you a good idea on working in Unity for *Windows Phone* and *Windows Store Apps*.